# Is the max limit of 4 GB on sql server 2005 express .mdf + .ldf or for .mdf only?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

Is the max limit of 4 GB on sql server 2005 express .mdf + .ldf or for .mdf only ? Kindly clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MDF + NDF's - basically the data files.

Logs dont count.

On 2008, File system store also does not count.

Comment: can you elaborate FILE SYSTEM SORE ?

Comment: @TomTom: I'm sure you meant **FILESTREAM** storage - storing large files in the SQL Server filesystem under transactional control

Comment: so does FILESTREAM in sql server 2005 express count in the 4GB limit ?

Comment: FILESTREAM does not exist in server 2005, it was a new feature for 2008

Comment: Which is pretty exactly why I said "on 2008" ;)